# How to use storage in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using google colab but my google drive is full. When I run the bellow code:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('df -h', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(str(p.communicate()[0], 'utf-8'))
```

I get this output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         359G   30G  310G   9% /
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            13G   12K   13G   1% /var/colab
/dev/sda1       365G   41G  325G  12% /opt/bin
shm             6.0G  4.0K  6.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /sys/firmware
drive            15G   15G  630M  96% /content/drive
```

As you can see my google drive is full and I cant store pickle files. So what is the other folders? It says 310G available in overlay folder. Is that a temp folder? Can I move files from colab to another folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain more Drive storage by signing up for a paid storage plan here:
https://one.google.com/about#upgrade

100 GB is $20/yr.